# C# Send keystroke to DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sendkeys

I have a [DateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630097/editable-date-in-datagridview-using-datetimepicker) cell in my DataGridView.  I'd like to be able to enter edit mode and drop the calendar when a button is clicked.  I'm able to do the first part without difficulty but the second isn't working.  If I have a standalone DateTimePicker the SendKeys call does work as expected.

```
//Select the cell and enter edit mode -  works
myDGV.CurrentCell = myDGV[calColumn.Index, e.RowIndex];
myDGV.BeginEdit(true);

//Send an ALt-Down keystroke to drop the calendar  - doesn't work
SendKeys.SendWait("%{DOWN}");
```

From debugging I believe that the problem is that the keystroke is being sent to the DGV and not the specific cell that I'm trying to edit.  The reason I think is is that I've put code to log keys received by the grids KeyPress and KeyDown events.  They log my arrowing around the grid and the keys sent by SendKeys, but not those from when I'm editing a cell by typing in it.

Comment: I don't think you can send the keys to a particular cell. You'll probably have to track what cell you are in and when the DGV receives the event, you handle it.

Comment: @0A0D I'm not sure I follow what you're suggesting I do.  AFAIK there's no provided method to drop the calendar if you're suggesting I just call it directly.  The only things I found were this, and equally non-functional code that sent a mouseclick (same problem as the keystrokes).

Comment: Why not just position a DateTimePicker over the cell and close it when the selection is made or someone clicks on a different cell? I don't have the code here but I will post it tomorrow. This is what I have done in the past.

Comment: @0A0D  That sounds like it would work.  Please post the code when you can.

Comment: See my answer. I forgot that I had posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently revisited this issue because the implementation provided by 0A0D didn't always play nicely with keyboard navigation of the grid (arrows/tab).  At times it was possible to bypass the `DateTimePicker` and enter text into the `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`.  This caused my validation logic to freak out; and after failing to find a way to prevent the slip around from happening I decided to try and get the custom column working again.

The fix turned out to be very simple.  I created an extended `DateTimePicker` with a method to send the keystroke needed to display the calendar.

```
/// <summary>
/// Extended DateTimePicker with a method to programmatically display the calendar.
/// </summary>
class DateTimePickerEx : DateTimePicker
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd, // handle to destination window
    Int32 msg, // message
    Int32 wParam, // first message parameter
    Int32 lParam // second message parameter
    );

    const Int32 WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;

    /// <summary>
    /// Displays the calendar input control.
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowCalendar()
    {
        Int32 x = Width - 10;
        Int32 y = Height / 2;
        Int32 lParam = x + y * 0x00010000;

        PostMessage(Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 1, lParam);
    }
}
```

I then modified the [MSDN DateTime column example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) to have `CalendarEditingControl` inherit from `DateTimePickerEx`.

Then in the form hosting the `DataGridView` I used the `EditingControl` property to call the `ShowCalendar()` method.

```
DateTimePickerEx dtp = myDataGridView.EditingControl as DateTimePickerEx;
if (dtp != null)
    dtp.ShowCalendar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer on [C# Winforms DataGridView Time Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807621/c-winforms-datagridview-time-column/1814455#1814455). I believe it will fit your needs perfectly. You can also use it for a column that has a ComboBox.

Comment: @0A0D  On second look your solution is missing the final step.  Sending the selection from the DTP back to the grid/datasource.

Comment: @0A0D OK.  I was just curious how you went about it, because my implementation required changes to one of the methods you provided.  I saved the cell location and set a flag in the setNewCellDate method, and then checked for the flag and used the cell location to save the data in the DateTimePicker's VisibleChanged event.

Comment: @Dan: Whatever works for you but this method is certainly better than messing with a DateTimePicker cell :)

Comment: I ended up moving the code to save from the VisibleChanged event to the Leave and KeyPress (if the user pressed enter) events to handle tabing out of the DTP and closing it by pressing enter respectively.  This also required setting tab order so that the DTP is immediately followed by the DGV.